# Compiling/Linking CUDA and CPP Source Files

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, linker, cuda, g++

I am working through a sample program that uses both C++ source code as well as CUDA.  This is the essential content from my four source files.

matrixmul.cu (main CUDA source code):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cutil.h>
#include "assist.h"
#include "matrixmul.h"

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    ...
    computeGold(reference, hostM, hostN, Mh, Mw, Nw);  //reference to .cpp file
    ...
}
```

matrixmul_gold.cpp (C++ source code, single function, no main method):

```
void computeGold(float * P, const float * M, const float * N, int Mh, int Mw, int Nw)
{

    ...
}
```

matrixmul.h (header for matrixmul_gold.cpp file)

```
#ifndef matrixmul_h
#define matrixmul_h

extern "C"
void computeGold(float * P, const float * M, const float * N, int Mh, int Mw, int Nw);
#endif
```

assist.h (helper functions)

I am trying to compile and link these files so that they, well, work.  So far I can get matrixmul_gold.cpp compiled using:

```
g++ -c matrixmul_gold.cpp
```

And I can compile the CUDA source code with out errors using:

```
nvcc -I/home/sbu/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc -L/home/sbu/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/lib matrixmul.cu -c -lcutil_x86_64
```

But I just end up with two .O files.  I've tried a lot of different ways to link the two .O files but so far it's a no-go.  What's the proper approach?

UPDATE:  As requested, here is the output of:

```
nm matrixmul_gold.o matrixmul.o | grep computeGold

nm: 'matrixmul.o': No such file
0000000000000000 T _Z11computeGoldPfPKfS1_iii
```

I think the 'matrixmul.o' missing error is because I am not actually getting a successful compile when running the suggested compile command:

```
nvcc -I/home/sbu/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc -L/home/sbu/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/lib -o matrixmul matrixmul.cu matrixmul_gold.o -lcutil_x86_64
```

UPDATE 2: I was missing an `extern "C"` from the beginning of matrixmul_gold.cpp.  I added that and the suggested compilation command works great.  Thank you!

Comment: There will never be a matrixmul object emitted, because the nvcc invocation doesn't make one, it just compiles and links to the executable directly from a temporary object. The problem is name mangling. Your compute_gold *definition* lacks an `extern "C"`, so you are getting C++ linkage in the object file, but later telling the compiler to expect C linkage. Change one or the other...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conventionally you would use whichever compiler you are using to compile the code containing the main subroutine to link the application. In this case you have the main in the `.cu`, so use nvcc to do the linking. Something like this:

```
$ g++ -c matrixmul_gold.cpp
$ nvcc -I/home/sbu/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc \
-L/home/sbu/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/lib \
-o matrixmul matrixmul.cu matrixmul_gold.o -lcutil_x86_64
```

This will link an executable binary called `matrimul` from `matrixmul.cu`, `matrixmul_gold.o` and the cutil library (implicitly nvcc will link the CUDA runtime library and CUDA driver library as well).

Comment: This explanation makes sense to me as a concept, than you.  The first g++ command worked successfully, but the second nvcc compiler command returned the following error:

`/tmp/tmpxft_0000187a_00000000-13_matrixmul.o: In function 'main': 
tmpxft_0000187a_00000000-1_matrixmul.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xbc8): undefined reference to 'computeGold' 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @user1644184 It is somewhat likely that you are not telling us the whole story. Please update your question with the output from `nm matrixmul_gold.o matrixmul.o | grep computeGold`.

Comment: @EmployedRussian, I updated the end of the post with the requested information.  I tried to provide the important code fragments; I can post the rest tomorrow.

Comment: @user1644184 This: `_Z11computeGoldPfPKfS1_iii` is a C++ mangled name. Its presence in `matrixmul_gold.o` is *inconsistent* with the source snippets you provided (which clearly have `extern "C"` in `matrixmul.h`. Conclusion: you have either modified `matrixmul.h`, or you have several copies of it, and the wrong one being used.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: It probably isn't inconsistent. `matrixmul_gold.cpp` lacks an `extern "C"` in the definition of `computeGold`. That should result in C++ linkage for that function, and result in the error during linking.

Comment: @talonmies I added an extern "C" to the beginning of matrixmul_gold.cpp and it all works perfectly using your compiling commands.

Comment: @talonmies The `extern "C"` should not be required in `matrixmul_gold.cpp` *so long* as it `#includes` `matrixmul.h`, and *so long* as the header has `extern "C"`.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: I don't believe that is correct. The definition controls the linkage model of the emitted code, and if it lacks an external "C", name mangling and C++ linkage is assumed. My understanding is that a forward declaration doesn't define the emitted linkage within the compilation unit, the definition does.

Comment: @talonmies Your understanding is incorrect. Try compiling this source: `extern "C" int foo(); int foo() { return 42;}`, and then run it through `nm`. You'll see `foo` (C-linkage) being defined, and not `_Z3foov`.